# How to order rows of a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with different columns (Client, Provider, Project number, etc) and I want that the user have the possibility to order the rows in an ascendent way. To do so, I have created this sentence:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `Project Control` ORDER BY '".$_GET['order']."' ASC";
```

and the i create buttons like those:

```
 <input type="button" value="Order by project number"   
onclick="location.href='VistaControl(Pgmaestra).ph p?order=project number';"/>
```

The problem is that when I click in those buttons, the webpage actualizates and the direction changes, but nothing is ordered...
 Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you echo your SQL statement you'll find

```
ORDER BY 'project number'
```

You need backticks in MySQL like so

```
ORDER BY `project number`
```

to delimit column names containing spaces.